# How do we align legends to be on the left hand side of a pie chart?

Tags: codenameone

I request for help aligning the legends of a pie chart to the left. By default it aligns to the bottom but I want them on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the draw legend API in `PieChart` or better yet draw it manually using a Container with some labels. You can place it in a layered layout on top of the pie chart anywhere you want or just place it in the EAST/WEST side of that chart using a border layout.